# Are the Control & Meta "digit argument" bindings duplicates?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

As far as I can tell the Meta and Control `digit-argument` bindings (`C-1, C-2, C-3`, `M-1, M-2, M-3`) are duplicates.

There are so few single-modifier, single-key bindings available, it seems like a perfect opportunity for personal bindings.

Is there any special reason one shouldn't use, for example, all the Meta-digit bindings for their own needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are duplicates. If you want to use one of them for your own purposes, I would recommend to keep the meta ones and rebind the control ones. One reason to keep the meta ones is that if you run Emacs in a terminal, most terminals don't transmit <kbd>*digit*</kbd> differently from plain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*digit*</kbd>, which makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*digit*</kbd> bindings inaccessible. On the other hand text terminals transmit <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>*digit*</kbd> as <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>*digit*</kbd>. Another reason to keep the meta bindings is that they are the same bindings that let you type <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>*digit*</kbd>…, since the <kbd>Meta</kbd> (`M-`) modifier is equivalent to the
<kbd>Esc</kbd> (`ESC`) prefix.

If you really want, you can even rebind both, since the same functionality is also available by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then digits without any modifier. So for example all of the following are equivalent and move the point 12 words to the left:

```
C-1 C-2 C-left
M-1 M-2 M-b
C-u 1 2 C-left
ESC 1 2 C-left
M-1 C-2 M-b
…
```

Answer (score 3):

They are duplicates, indeed. The reason they exist is to make it more ergonomic to type digit arguments regardless if the next command uses Meta or Control. For example, typing `C-5 M-f` is very convoluted; `M-5 M-f` is much easier.

You are free to bind them to your own commands if you like.